# Groovy set isolation level - locking UPDATE sql transcation

Tags: sql, sql-server, groovy, locking, isolation-level

Is it possible to lock UPDATE transaction in pure Groovy for writing (leave it free for reading)?

DB behind is MSSQL.

I see there are ways how to do it in Java, or in the level of procedure but I am interested in the groovy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible using optimistic Transaction Isolation Levels: READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT. They use row versioning for reads instead of shared locks, so when a row is updated (and locked with exclusive lock), its content copied to the Version Store in tempdb, so other process doesn't wait for update finishing, but just read previous version or row from the Version Store.

Here is more reading about snaphot isolation levels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx

As both of them need Version Store in tempdb, they can't be just specified in a connection, instead of that ALTER DATABASE is needed: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: My question targets more to how to do it programmaticly in Groovy (directly) when executing sql query. Not on DB level. Would you know?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Locking is a storage engine behavior. And there is no way to allow versioning without altering the database. On client level, you can only change query or connection behavior. For example, you can use read uncommitted isolation level for your connection or NOLOCK hint for your query (which is the same). But it will not be the same with SNAPSHOT isolation because you will read dirty (uncommitted) data in this case.

Comment: This looks to be adressing my problem: http://gik.firetrot.com/index.php/2013/04/17/sql-queries-under-transaction-in-groovy/